# jQuery Exit Popup Redirect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, alert, confirm

So I've been looking around for hours, testing multiple versions, testing some of my own theories and I just can't seem to get it working.

What I'm trying to do is use `alert` or `confirm` (or whatever works) so popup a dialog when a user tries to navigate away from a purchase form. I just want to ask them "Hey, instead of leaving, why not get a free consultation?" and redirect the user to the "Free Consultation" form.

This is what I have so far and I'm just not getting the right results.

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){
        var pop = confirm('Are you sure you want to leave? Why not get a FREE consultation?');
        if (pop) {

            window.location.href('http://www.mydomain/free-consultation/');
        } else {
            // bye bye
        }
    });

    $("form").submit(function() {
        $(window).unbind("beforeunload");
    });
```

Comment: Note that Firefox will ignore any message you set and display its own: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=588292

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the `beforeunload` and `alert()`, I decided to check whether or not the users mouse has left the document. See code below:

```
$(document).bind('mouseleave', function(event) {
    // show an unobtrusive modal
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is showing confirm dialog to user, want to stay or leave page. Not exactly what you looking for but maybe it will be useful for start.

```
function setDirtyFlag() {
    needToConfirm = true; //Call this function if some changes is made to the web page and requires an alert
    // Of-course you could call this is Keypress event of a text box or so...
}

function releaseDirtyFlag() {
    needToConfirm = false; //Call this function if dosent requires an alert.
    //this could be called when save button is clicked 
}


window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
function confirmExit() {
    if (needToConfirm)
        return "You have attempted to leave this page. If you have made any changes to the fields without clicking the Save button, your changes will be lost. Are you sure you want to exit this page?";
}
```

Script taken from http://forums.devarticles.com/showpost.php?p=156884&postcount=18

Comment: I don't want to just stay. I want to redirect the user to another page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
window.onunload = redirurl;
            function redirurl() {
                alert('Check this Page');
                window.location.href('http://www.google.com');
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether it will help.
You need to stop the propagation before showing the Confirm / Alert.

Please refer http://jonathonhill.net/2011-03-04/catching-the-javascript-beforeunload-event-the-cross-browser-way/

Look at the last comment.